# How can you manipulate Rust env::args and avoid "temporary value dropped while borrowed"?

Tags: rust

I have no idea how to follow the compiler suggestion: `consider using a let binding to create a longer lived value`.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=644d92d34836bee265d876357e291433)

```
#![allow(unused)]
fn main() {
let a_dir=std::env::args().nth(2);
    
    let  dir:&str=match a_dir{
      Some (ref a)=> &format!("./{}/**/*.liquid",a) as &str,
      None=>{"./**/*.liquid"},
    };
}
```

```
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
 --> src/main.rs:6:23
  |
5 |     let  dir:&str=match a_dir{
  |          --- borrow later stored here
6 |       Some (ref a)=> &format!("./{}/**/*.liquid",a) as &str,
  |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^       - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
  |                       |
  |                       creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
  |
  = note: consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```rust
#![allow(unused)]
fn main() {
    let a_dir = std::env::args().nth(2);

    let dir: &str = match a_dir {
        Some(ref a) => &format!("./{}/**/*.liquid", a) as &str,
        None => "./**/*.liquid",
    };
}
```

In your code, inside the `Some` case of match, you are creating an owned `String`. Which is dropped at the end of you match block.

```rust
format!("./{}/**/*.liquid", a);
```

This produces a [`String`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.push) and you return a reference to it.

But at the end of the match block, the `String` produced by `format!()` has actually dropped so you are trying to return a dangling reference because of which compiler rejects your code.

---

> "consider using a let binding to create a longer lived value"

In simple terms, compiler is suggesting you to create the `String` before and store it somewhere so it doesn't get dropped and you are able to return a valid reference.

Going by the compiler's suggestion:

```rust
#![allow(unused)]
fn main() {
    let a_dir = std::env::args().nth(2);

    let string;
    let dir: &str = match a_dir {
        Some(ref a) => {
            string = format!("./{}/**/*.liquid", a);
            &string
        },
        None => "./**/*.liquid",
    };
}
```

This will create a variable named `string` that will live long enough and you store the `String` being generated from `format!()` in the `string`. Then you return the reference to the `string`.

Although a better way would be to use a `String` instead here:

```rust
#![allow(unused)]
fn main() {
    let a_dir = std::env::args().nth(2);
    
    let dir = a_dir
        .as_ref()
        .map(|val| format!("./{}/**/*.liquid", val))
        .unwrap_or_else(|| "./**/*.liquid".to_string());
}
```

If you ever want `&str` you can simply do `dir.as_str()`.

Comment: You can even declare the string as `let string`; That way `string` doesn't need to be mutable, and the compiler is smart enough to figure out that it is correctly initialized in all code paths where it's used.

Comment: @user4815162342, makes sense. Made the change.

Comment: This is good enough for a match block but what about a for loop, where the value of `string` would change at each iteration?

Comment: @theberzi I don't exactly understand what you mean but roughly it seems the same to me: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b871dcd29c34556e86481479c1376321

Comment: Feel free to share a playground link if the above example is not what you meant.

Comment: @MihirLuthra My use-case involves [using `format!` inside a loop](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2d76eee0e2cc109752264bedd178f92c).

Comment: @theberzi https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f7d8a708f43f9d55a2e8a04d85100933

Comment: @MihirLuthra Ooh I see what the issue is now. Thank you so much.